# Books for learning applied seismic geophysics

Tags: geophysics

I am a software developer trying to learn applied geophysics. Specifically I am interested in seismic attributes. I have a strong background in mathematics and signal processing and therefore grasp the theory quite easily. However the geology and the applied part is a problem for me. What i would like is a book/tutorial that takes the reader trough very detailed concrete examples with no theory whatsoever. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'examples' and 'with no theory whatsoever'? Do you mean geological examples, with no geological theory, or attribute analysis examples, with no seismic theory? Most (useful) case studies have a bit of both...

Comment: Many books use a lot of pages describing the theory. This information is easy to get hold off. What is difficult is to learn a bit of the practical knowledge a seismic interpreter holds without working as a junior geophysicist. As an example say that the tutorial extracts several seismic attributes with different settings (timegates)on an interpreted horizon and displays the images: Next the tutorial goes on to pinpoint say a channel on the images and explain why it appears clearer on one of the images. Also the tutorial should explain briefly about the geology and ideally distribute the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a list of resources I've compiled before. Between them, maybe you'll find what you're after:

- Some important geophysics papers and books: [Must-read geophysics](http://subsurfwiki.org/wiki/Must-read_geophysics).
- [Six books about seismic interpretation](http://www.agilegeoscience.com/blog/2013/3/31/six-books-about-seismic-interpretation.html) — most of these include something about seismic attributes.
- [Six books about seismic analysis](http://www.agilegeoscience.com/blog/2014/7/18/six-books-about-seismic-analysis.html) — more quantitative, and usually with lots of theory. I especially recommend Simm & Bacon.

I recommend learning what you can about rocks — their genesis, their properties, and especially their acoustic and elastic behaviour. If possible, go and see outcrops or at least cores. If possible, take classes in sedimentology, petrology, or even reservoir engineering.

You need to read about *integrated interpretation*; here are some other phrases to look for: *well ties*, *phase estimation*, *spectral decomposition*, *seismic inversion*, *pre-stack seismic analysis*, *AVO*. I recommend subscribing to [CSEG *Recorder*](http://csegrecorder.com/), [EAGE *First Break*](http://fb.eage.org/) and [SEG *Leading Edge*](http://library.seg.org/journal/tle).

Good luck in your quest!

Comment: Thank you very much kwinkunks! BTW I enjoy reading the agilegeoscience blog.